Custom Stripe checkout embedded - listen for user changes in checkout
Hello everyone :-) I hope I can find a good developer who would have time to help develop my problem.
I have a problem with integrating custom embedded stripe checkout for my web application.
The problem is that I want to implement parcel locker logic.
Parcel lockers have their own iframe, so based on the user's selection in the "shipment" radio buttons, a specific modal should be launched, which will contain an iframe map of this specific supplier.  
For example, the user selects "DHL Parcel" from the list of available delivery options. Now I need to somehow get a listener that will respond to me that the user has selected a specific option. This is to trigger my modal, which will allow me to select a parcel locker and after selecting it, enter the value of this parcel locker in the custom field.
I already have the logic that allows me to enter the selected parcel machine into the form fields. The main problem is listening for the user's change in the scope of delivery. Stripe does not allow delving into the query selector of this iframe checkout so I can't implement any addEventListner.
Checkout.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Accept a payment</title>
    <meta content="A demo of a payment on Stripe" name="description"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script defer src="checkout.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="checkout">

</div>
</body>
</html>

Server.js:
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:63342';

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      ui_mode: 'embedded',
      payment_method_types: ['card', 'p24', 'blik'],
      billing_address_collection: 'auto',
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ['PL'],
      },
      line_items: [
        {
          // Replace '{{PRICE_ID}}' with your actual Price ID
          price: 'price_XXXXXXXXXXX',
          quantity: 1,
        },
        {
          // Replace '{{PRICE_ID}}' with your actual Price ID
          price: 'price_XXXXXXXXXXX',
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      phone_number_collection: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      mode: 'payment',
      return_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/return.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      automatic_tax: { enabled: true },
      custom_fields: [
        {
          key: 'nip',
          label: {
            type: 'custom',
            custom: 'NIP',
          },
          type: 'text',
        },
        {
          key: 'paczkomat',
          label: {
            type: 'custom',
            custom: 'Paczkomat',
          },
          type: 'text',
        },
      ],
      shipping_options: [
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: 2000,
              currency: 'pln',
            },
            display_name: 'Kurier',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: 2000,
              currency: 'pln',
            },
            display_name: 'Paczkomat InPost',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: 2000,
              currency: 'pln',
            },
            display_name: 'Paczkomat DHL',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: 0,
              currency: 'pln',
            },
            display_name: 'Odbiór osobisty',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    // Ensure the clientSecret is being sent correctly
    if (!session.client_secret) {
      throw new Error('Failed to retrieve client secret');
    }

    res.json({ clientSecret: session.client_secret });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating checkout session:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});


app.get('/session-status', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
    res.send({
      status: session.status,
      customer_email: session.customer_details.email,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({error: error.message});
  }
});

app.listen(63342, () => console.log('Running on port 63342'));

Checkout.js:
const stripe = Stripe("pk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXX");

initialize();

// Create a Checkout Session
async function initialize() {
  const fetchClientSecret = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      if (!data.clientSecret) {
        throw new Error('Client secret not found in the response');
      }

      return data.clientSecret;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching client secret:', error);
      return undefined; // Ensure that an undefined value is not returned, triggering the error
    }
  };

  const checkout = await stripe.initEmbeddedCheckout({
    fetchClientSecret,
  });

  // Mount Checkout
  checkout.mount('#checkout');

  // Nasłuchiwanie na zmiany w metodzie dostawy
  checkout.on('change', (event) => {
    if (event.shippingOption) {
      console.log('Wybrana metoda dostawy:', event.shippingOption);
    }
  });
}

checkout.on('change', (event) not working...
Even if it turns out that I can't listen for changes in delivery options and do my logic for this, I plan to do multi-step in cart at worst. This means that I will select a delivery option there and possibly a parcel locker from InPost or DHL maps, but then there is another problem, how to pass this information to a custom field called "PARCEL" and immediately set the selected delivery option? The user should no longer be able to change these things (unless they go back to cart) and then click "go to payment" which will again generate a session checkout for me.
I have a lot of ambiguities in my mind, I don't know how to approach this. I'm implementing Stripe to Webflow, my client has requirements for Polish payment gateways, Webflow doesn't allow it, I have to use custom checkout. I don't want to choose another option like Foxy.io or Snipcart.
